# Response status code does not indicate success: 426 (InvalidRequest)

Tags: c#, azure, authenticator

I am getting the issue on my deployed API's, earlier it was working properly but after 31 May 2023 on words we are getting status code 426 (InvalidRequest). And I'm not sure is that anything got changed on Microsoft authentication level. If yes, what changes we need to do on already deployed API's? Thanks.

> [HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success:
> 426 (InvalidRequest).]
> System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode() +210
> Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory.WsFedMetadataRetriever.GetSigningKeys(String
> metadataEndpoint, TimeSpan backchannelTimeout, HttpMessageHandler
> backchannelHttpHandler) +160
> Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory.WsFedCachingSecurityTokenProvider.RetrieveMetadata()
> +423    Microsoft.Owin.Security.ActiveDirectory.WsFedCachingSecurityTokenProvider..ctor(String
> metadataEndpoint, ICertificateValidator
> backchannelCertificateValidator, TimeSpan backchannelTimeout,
> HttpMessageHandler backchannelHttpHandler) +361
> Owin.WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationExtensions.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(IAppBuilder
> app, WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions options)
> +163    Startup.ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) in C:\Code\Release\API\App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs:13
> API.Startup.Configuration(IAppBuilder app) in
> C:\Code\Release\API\Startup.cs:9

Can somebody assist on this? Thanks.

Comment: A 426 status code is "Upgrade Required". The typical example is that you are using an older version of TLS that the site does not support

Comment: Thanks for your details. Could you please guide me, where I need to upgrade?. Since our API's are deployed into azure and hope there is no changes on code side. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the error code **426 (InvalidRequest)** indicates that the `Upgradation of software` to the latest version is required which supports the latest authentication protocols.

- It can also be because the deployed API is not compatible with the new protocols.
- Check if your API is compatible with the latest authentication protocols.

As @*flydog57* mentioned, I feel you need to upgrade/downgrade the TLS version of your API according to run the application without any issues.

***To update TLS version:***

Open your API=> Security=>Protocols + Ciphers:
Select the TLS version according to your requirement=>Save.

*By default, TLS version 1.2 is enabled for both Client and Backend protocols.*

[image]

**References:**
 [Manage protocols and ciphers in Azure API Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-manage-protocols-ciphers)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Looks required TLS got enabled on API Management side. Just wanted to check, our API's has been developed .NET framework 4.5, which is older. And we haven't add any explicit code to support the TLS version. Does .NET framework version causing the issue?. Because this was working fine till last week, not sure if anything got changed on framework level. Please correct me if I am wrong into my observation. Thanks

Comment: @GanapathyA, Yes you are right. .Net framework version of your application should be compatible with TLS version. And also sometimes this happens if there is any changes from Microsoft side. That could be the reason you are getting the above error even if it was working before

Comment: @PravallikaKV, We have guessed it right. Due to framework version on our existing application this issue has been occurred. Looks MSDN has been communicated year back about supporting TLS version. So we need to upgrade into 4.6 above. Thanks